# why do i keep getting "Type Error" problem when trying to webscrape?

Tags: python, python-requests

Why do I keep getting this "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'" when I run

> > > res = requests.get('https://automatetheboringstuff.com/files/rj.txt')

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module
>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 49, in get

    return request('get', url, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 38, in request

    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 232, in _get_conn

 return conn or self._new_conn()

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 199, in _new_conn
    strict=self.strict)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'
```

Comment: I just tried with request 2.22.0 and python 3.7.4 and it works. Which version of `requests` are you using?

Comment: I upgraded requests and it worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the latest version of requests :)